# Positive lookbehind with an optional character

Tags: regex

From the string `HelloWorld`, I would like to get `World`.

The String could be either `HelloWorld` or it could be `Hello|World` as well, where `|` is optional. I am wondering how I could get `World` with or without the character `|`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(?<=Hello)?\|.+
```

https://regex101.com/r/xebaX9/2

Comment: Like this? `\bHello\|?(.+)`  https://regex101.com/r/V2CEUa/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird absolutely! My problem was that I set `?` in the wrong position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optionally match the pipe and then use a capturing group

```
\bHello\|?(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V2CEUa/1/)

Or you could use the positive lookbehind with an optional pipe and start the match with an uppercase char

```
(?<=\bHello\|?)[A-Z].*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8KTaRI/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group:

```
Hello\|?([A-Za-z]+)
```

the desired output is in capture group 1.

[image]

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/A28uJ5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Most regex engines disallow variable length look behinds, but you can use an alternation of two different constant-length look behinds!

```
(?<=Hello)\w+|(?<=Hello\|)\w+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/OzgfopgyytWQHq).

Note that (unlike all other comments/answers so far that don’t require an engine that supports variable length look behinds, which is most engines), the *whole* match is your target (no using groups).

Comment: @Thefourthbird I see. I have qualified my comment.